# Convert curl command to ajax with specific header

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want write this curl command with ajax

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept:plication/com.biomedian.v1' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://mywebsite.com/api/users/request_login -d '{"phone_number": "+9891400020"}'
```

I tired this code but it's not work

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mywebsite.com/api/users/request_login",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: '{"phone_number":"+9891400020"}',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept:plication/com.biomedian.v1");
  },
  success: function(returnhtml) {
    $("#result").html(returnhtml);
    $("#loadingimg").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You might want to look at CORS. Also, the accept header is incorrectly set.

Comment: @Hritik yes i already did CORS config and dont get any CORS error how can i set accept header correctly?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my side. About the accept header, I suppose you want 'application' with an 'a'